# Logging output in Eclipse WTP server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, logging

I'm running *Eclipse 3.5* with *Tomcat* (integrated from *WTP*) and I want to see the output logs in txt other than just the console

Cant find it in my *eclipse/workspace* nor in the local *Tomcat 6* installation directory

Any clues how to enable these?

I've also enabled `org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve` and the output scrolls by on console which I want to see in txt

Answer (score 11):

In the Servers tab:

1. Double-click on the Tomcat Server.
2. Click on "Open launch configuration".
3. Click on the "Common" tab.
4. Check the "File" checkbox and specify a file.
5. Restart the Tomcat server.

This is based on codesta's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5045247/112335

Answer (score 2):

Check you Eclipse installation dir - logs are sometimes hiding in there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup - I've seen some in `Eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\logs\`

Comment: no, i checked that already as my question says. there is one access log but no error logs, and no requestdumper output in any log. On a Tomcat outside of Eclipse - this usually appears in the catalina log.

Comment: @shiny - I'm not talking about your workspace; @JoseK is. I am asking if you checked where your Eclipse folder itself lives, there are often logs in **both** locations :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ps aux | grep tomcat
```

Check for the value of -Dwtp.deploy
Go to that directory and you will find logs folder, web-apps etc there.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on your logger configuration and other technologies you use.
They should be where other answers say they are but for me this was not the case.
Finding them was a real PITA, but I found them on the same drive in which the Tomcat (or Eclipse ?) was running under:

```
THE_SAME_DRIVE_AS_YOUR_TOMCAT\tomcat\logs
```