# Eclipse Tomcat log files

Tags: eclipse, file, tomcat, logging

I find the similar question - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233053/where-can-i-view-tomcats-log-file-in-eclipse)

But it doesn't help any.
Near .metadata I didn't find any files *.log.
May be Tomcat when run from Eclipse doesn't write log files?
Thanks.

Comment: To configure this inside of eclipse, view the discussion here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233053/where-can-i-view-tomcat-log-files-in-eclipse

Comment: Please select the answer which worked for you.

Answer (score 8):

Look in `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\logs`

Source: [Logging output in Eclipse WTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591702/logging-output-in-eclipse-wtp-server)

Answer (score 6):

Yes. If you want the logs like those for a default Tomcat 6 installation started using startup.bat, you need to add the following JVM arguments:

```
-Dcatalina.base="C:\Tomcat6"
-Dcatalina.home="C:\Tomcat6"
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\Tomcat6\conf\logging.properties"
```

Also add C:\Tomcat6\bin and C:\Tomcat6\lib to the classpath if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Go to server view --> double click on server --> In Overview tab you will find server locations click on this to extend part --> In this part you will find server path --> In server path you will find logs folder In that folders log files will be available