# How can I tell tomcat (within eclipse) to make the log file a rolling log file?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, logging

There was a great question/answer on setting up tomcat (within eclipse) to write log files to disk (see answer by @codesta):
[Where can I view Tomcat log files in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233053/where-can-i-view-tomcat-log-files-in-eclipse)

Through the Edit Launch Configuration Properties wizard in eclipse I can specify which file to write my logs to. However, since it is a single file, it gets overwritten every time the server restarts. I already have access to the current log through the console in eclipse, but is there a way to make this a rolling file so that I can have history?

I have played around with only specifying a directory in the file path, but then no logs are written out.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions to use log4j for Tomcat's internal logging:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j

The tomcat-juli jars that you need can be found here:

http://apache.osuosl.org/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.35/bin/extras/

Substitute whatever version of Tomcat you're using.  Your CATALINA_HOME for the purpose of libraries will be wherever you have Tomcat installed, but the CATALINA_HOME for your configuration files will likely be:

workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0

Comment: I'm mostly concerned about the application logs (we are using logback for those), not the internal logging of tomcat.