# Creating and debugging app with springmvc and eclipse with internal server

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I currently have a sprimgmvc app that uses maven. I am currently using mvn:package to build war and deploy it to tomcat to develop and this is getting very cumbersome. I dont have the eclipse configured to automatically build and deploy to tomcat for that matter?

Can anyone please provide me steps that I need to take so that if I make any changes in my project I can just hit save and run and it will deploy to the tomcat OR a way in which I dont use tomcat but use maybe jetty or something else to build and test my app?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at STS? It has preinstalled integrations for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

download STS > Import your project as maven project to the new workspace > mvn install (only once to download all your dependencies) > run AS > Server > baam!
For any other eclipse version pretty much the same but you need to open the server window and configure tomcat , basically open the server tab > new > select your tomcat installation path and then .. just run it on the server. You can even modify code while running your app.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work using some helpers from: [Running Tomcat from within Eclipse always gives me 404 (but index.html works)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971808/running-tomcat-from-within-eclipse-always-gives-me-404-but-index-html-works) and following these steps:

1. I suspected that there was something wrong with the initial set up in eclipse. So, I closed the project in eclipse using: Right Click project > Close Project
2. Then I deleted any files related with eclipse from the folder. These were: .settings, .project, .classpath
3. I then Re-imported the project as maven project.
4. I used Window > Show view > server view
5. In the server view I created a new server  and pointed it to XAMPP > tomcat since I already had tomcat.
6. Right click on the project > Run As > Run on Server.
7. It should run properly at that point in the browser as well

Make sure to check Right Click Project > Properties > Deployment Assembly - There should be Maven Dependencies added to the project and the deploy path for that should be "WEB-INF/lib"

Answer (score 0):

here is a my way to debug and run maven web project with eclipse. though code is not **hot deployed** but it works fine for me.

Steps are as follows

- open command prompt and go to your project directory. Lets say it is **/opt/myhome/myproj**
- run **mvnDebug tomcat:run** command, make sure you have **mvn** and **mvnDebug** at system path
- A message will be appeared like one mentioned in screenshot attached below, this states that maven is waiting for remote connection.

  [image: Waiting for remote debugging]

Now we need to Remotely connect to maven from IDE. To do that

- Right click on the project and select "DebugAs" ---> "Debug configuration"
  [image: Select Debug Configuration]
- Add an new entry under Remote Java application with highlighted details and then select **Debug** button.
  [image]
- switch back to your terminal and you will get a screen like one displayed below
  [image]
- your web app is ready to debug, put a break point and call it and your IDE will switch to debug perspective
  [image]

We are done with it. now if you make some changes in your code. you need to stop it from terminal with Ctrl-C and re-execute **mvnDebug tomcat:run** and then Remote Debug from IDE.

As i mentioned in starting code is not hot deployable as in local debug mode but it is pretty much better approach than rebuilding war and deploy it to external tomcat instance.

I hope this targets your query