# How to use breakpoints in eclipse for Spring MVC

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to use breakpoints using eclipse but its not working. Here is the project debugging overview

[image: Eclipse Spring Project Display]

Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView loginvalidateForm(ModelMap model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("loginForm") Login login, BindingResult result, HttpSession session) {

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("result", "All Fields are neccessary");
            return new ModelAndView("index",model);
        }
        if(emp_service.validateLogin(login.getUsername(), login.getPassword()))
        {
            List<Employee> user_info = emp_service.getUserinfo(login.getUsername());
            session.setAttribute("session_username", login.getUsername()); //Add value to session variable
            model.addAttribute("result", "Login Success");
            model.addAttribute("user_info", user_info);
            return new ModelAndView("LoginSuccess",model);
        }
        else
        {
            model.addAttribute("result", "Login Failure");
            return new ModelAndView("index",model);     
        }
    }
```

I put a break point at this line `if(result.hasErrors()){`, so when I click on login button, it should stop at the above line but it doesnt stops there. Why it is not working here?

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: Try logging something just before, so you can make sure it's actually executing.

Comment: There must be something more at play here. I've never faced an undeserved problem with breakpoints in Spring MVC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating and debugging app with springmvc and eclipse with internal server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307517/creating-and-debugging-app-with-springmvc-and-eclipse-with-internal-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are launching the server in **Debug** Mode and **NOT in Run Mode.**

Use the button shown in below image

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the pic they posted?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Don't confuse being in the Debug **Perspective** for having actually **launched** in Debug. If it were actually debugging, you would see expandable threads in the processes, and it would likely show the correct action name of `**Debug** on Server`.

Comment: Thanks!! That's what  wrong I was doing. Still while using F5, it goes into each and every internal class of java which is a pain in the head. Is it possible to skip internal java classes browsing, just browse only my code?

Comment: Also check out the **Step Filtering** preference page for setting packages and classes you never want to step through. http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fdebug%2Fref-step_filtering.htm

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate the steps --> right click project --> Debug As--> Debug on server --> Then the break points will work.....