# actionListener not triggered, where to look for error?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, actionlistener

Problems with form submit and action listeners in the following code:

```
<p:commandButton 
    id="btnOkId" 
    value="OK" 
    ajax="true" 
    type="submit" 
    actionListener="#{WatchfolderEditBean.save}" 
    action="#WatchfolderMgmtBean.refreshList}" 
    oncomplete="dlgEditWF.hide();" 
    update=":wfMgtForm:wfTable :editWFForm:messagesId" 
    process="@this" 
    styleClass="buttonOK"/>
```

When button is clicked, the form doesn't get submitted, I mean the setters in the dialog bean are not executed, so the variables stay `null`.

When `process="@this"` is removed, then the form gets submitted, setters are called, but - `actionListener` is not called.

Why the `actionListener` fails? Which log file should I look into to see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how it should be, processing only `@this` will not submit anything else your `p:commandButton`. The code `process="@this"` is pretty self-explanatory.

More info : [PrimeFaces User's Guide](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/primefaces/users-guide/more-ajax-info.pdf) under **4.2 Partial Processing**

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I got confused. So the real question is why does the `actionListener` get called only when I add `process` and not without it?

Comment: @Danijel I suspect a validation or convertion error, add `h:messages` to your view, you should get something.

Comment: OK, will try: I just added another row to the table: `<tr><td colspan="2"><h:messages layout="table"></h:messages></td></tr>`. Is this the only code I need to add? Nothing is shown, no messages.

Comment: Yes, pay attention at it's output, also check logs if you have any other kind of errors

Comment: I am running Tomcat inside Eclipse. Do you know which log should I look for, where is it placed?

Comment: @Danijel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233053/where-can-i-view-tomcat-log-files-in-eclipse

Comment: OK. Still nothing suspicious in the Tomcat log. Should I check any other logs? Are there JSF logs?

Comment: If your h:form and inner components is not to long, could you post it in your question?

Comment: OK, nailed it... it was a combination of a few java script and jsf errors, very hard to explain. Thanks for the help.