# Jersey 2.23 : Not able to enable LoggingFeature from web.xml

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I am trying to enable HTTP request/response logging in Jersey, running on Tomcat. My app is web.xml based and does not have an Application on ResourceConfig class.

This is what i have tried to enable LoggingFeature from my web.xml :

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>

<init-param>
    <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_LOGGER_LEVEL</param-name>
    <param-value>java.util.logging.Level.FINEST</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
    <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_LOGGER_NAME</param-name>
    <param-value>MyLoggerName</param-value>
</init-param>
```

but i don't see any Jersey logs in catalina.out or localhost_access.log

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I made it work on Tomcat running from within Eclipse:

1. Find out the path to tomcat running within Eclipse: [Where can I view Tomcat log files in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233053/where-can-i-view-tomcat-log-files-in-eclipse)
2. Create a `logging.properties` file there. In my case, the path was `.../EclipseWorkSpace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/conf`
   (You can copy this logging file from within your actual tomcat conf folder.)
3. Within your application, create a `logging.properties` file in `src/main/resources`. 
   (did not work when i directly created in `WEB-INF/classes` as mentioned in tomcat documentation :

> Example logging.properties for the servlet-examples web application to
>   be placed in WEB-INF/classes inside the web application:
>   from https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/logging.html
>   )

4. set your tomcat logging parameters in the above file, which overrides the default `logging.properties` file from `/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/conf` from inside your app:

   ```
   handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

   .level= FINE

   java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
   java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
   ```

This will log 'FINE' level logs from Tomcat.

5. Set logging properties in your jersey app:

   ```
   register(new LoggingFeature(Logger.getLogger(MyApplication.class.getName()), Level.INFO, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_TEXT, 2048));
   ```

OR

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

This will only log 'INFO' logs from jersey.

So, 4 and 5 effectively means that Tomcat would log all FINE logs, but Jersey would only log INFO logs, so in your log file (catalina.out) , you will only see INFO logs from Jersey, but FINE logs from everything else in Tomcat.